# update the last element of List

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections

I have a List

```
val first = List("A","B","C","D")
```

and I want to create a new list from it but change the last element only:

```
val newLastVal = "E"
val second = List("A","B","C","E")
```

can't figure this one out! Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a `Seq`!! or `List`?

Comment: hint: don't use `List` if you're changing any element except the head. Use `Vector`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can also use `.init` or `.dropRight(1)` to remove last element and then can add new item to list

```
val second=first.init:+newLastVal //preferable
```

OR

```
val second=first.dropRight(1):+newLastVal
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.updated(postion,value)`

```
val second=first.updated(first.length-1,newLastVal)
```